# RDS VPC privacy

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, vpc

I want to have different VPC for dev/test/prod and one separate VPC for share services like jenkins. I'll use VPC peering between the Shared Services VPC and each of the environments VPCs

Each environment will have its own RDS instance.

RDS setup has this option about instance public accesibily, and I'm confused about the "No EC2 instance or devices outside of the VPC will be able to connect" statement.
[image]

If I choose "no" will I still be able to connect to the dev RDS instance from the shared services VPC by using VPC peering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will be able to access from your 'shared services' VPC if you've peered the two VPCs.

Be sure to follow the [VPC peering guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html).  The biggest thing is to make sure the CIDR block ranges do not overlap and you'll have to set the security groups on each RDS instance to allow traffic from the Jenkins instance in the 'shared services' VPC